# Is there any way to get compiled CSS of angular2+ component

Tags: css, angular

Is there any way to get compiled CSS (As a string) of angular2+ component?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-graph',
  templateUrl: './test-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-graph.component.scss']
})
export class TestGraphComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

Is am looking for some method/Utility to get css defined in "test-graph.component.scss".

Answer (score 0):

command line: `sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css`

More about sass [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation)

Comment: I tried but didn't work.
I need it as string so, I can export it.

Comment: you want to compile scss file at runtime and get css value so you can use it dynamically through js ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get html through component factory resolver but CSS is missing.